# wrapping text in the dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to wrap dropdown text which is too long? see below example

```
 <div class="col-md-7">
       <select class="input-validation-error form-control" data-val="true" 
       data-val-required="обязательное поле/Required Field" id="FirstCategory" 
       name="FirstCategory">
            <option value="">Выбрать опции/Select Option...</option>
            <option value="3">Высокое давление/температура и подсолевые отложения:
              бурение, конструкция скважин и заканчивание/ design and completion</option>
       </select>
       <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstCategory" d
        ata-valmsg-replace="false" style="padding-left: 5px">обязательное поле/Required Field</span>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I feel like this issue could be solved through better design rather than a giant wrapped option

Comment: It's a browser-based control that doesn't support line breaks.